# Angular 2 can't get particular object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple API written in `Express` with the help of `MongoDB`, everything works fine except that my `Angular 2` can't get particular object. I can access list of objects, but when i try to get an object by `id` it returns me an error `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` that means he can't get it. I believe that problem is that `id` property in `MongoDB` isn't a number, but it should so I can get that object.

My code below:

**goal.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import {
  Goal ,
  GoalService
} from '../shared/index';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-goal',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'goal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['goal.component.css'],
  directives: [GoalComponent]
})

export class GoalComponent {
  goal: Goal;
  error: any;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private goalService: GoalService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let id = +params['id'];
      this.goalService.getGoal(id).then(goal => this.goal = goal);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

**goal.model.ts**

```
export class Goal {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  finish_date: Date;
}
```

**goal.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import '../../rxjs-operators';

import { Goal } from './goal.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class GoalService {

  private goalsUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/api/goals';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getGoals(): Promise<Goal[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.goalsUrl)
              .toPromise()
              .then(this.extractData)
              .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getGoal(id: number) {
    return this.getGoals()
               .then(goals => goals.filter(goal => goal.id === id)[0]);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }

  private handleError (error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

}
```

I tried to turn id into string and change it to _id, but no difference at all. So may be there are problems in something different, but it looks like id property is broken here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the problem is within your template since the data of the particular element is loaded asynchronously.

You could try to use the Elvis operator. Something like this:

```
{{goal?.name}}
```

Comment: Wow, I forgot about that. Thank you, it helped a lot. I wrapped the whole code in `<div *ngIf="goal"></div>` and now it works.